# show and hide list elements in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show and hide list elements (that I can't advice a individual class to) in a sequence, i.e. delayed.

this is my html…

```
<ul id="aclass">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($enties); ++$i) :
    <li class="animation">
        <div id="frame">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

so far I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function showpanel() {
    $("ul#aclass > li").each(function() {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
 });
     setTimeout(showpanel, 200)
});
```

I want to see the first li element for two seconds, then replaced but the second one for two seconds, then the next one etc.
I don't know how to select the "next" li element and to run the function on each element successively.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

Creative solution:

- CSS: Hide all panels except the first (with the help of `:first-child`)
- jQuery: keep moving the first child to the end periodically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var panelInterval;

    panelInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $("ul#aclass > li:first-child").appendTo("ul#aclass");
    }, 200)
});
```

```css
ul#aclass > li {
  display: none;
}
ul#aclass > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="aclass">
  <li>Panel 1</li>
  <li>Panel 2</li>
  <li>Panel 3</li>
  <li>Panel 4</li>
  <li>Panel 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice thought.  But you really should only use the technique of switching DOM elements around when it's the only option.  It is very much not the only option in this case.

Comment: Can you explain why it's a bad idea?

Comment: I don't think that's hard to see.  Switching up DOM elements (especially in a case such as this, where the elements are apparently ONLY selectable as children of the parent) means that everything in your CSS/javaScript that selects/acts upon those elements must also switch.  If any of these panels needs CSS or jQuery applied specifically to them, it will quickly become very difficult to select them.

Comment: Only if you rely on their order, which may or may not be relevant to the OP's case. You could give them IDs to refer to them regardless of their position, if that's a concern. That element order is particularly relevant to the OP is just as probable as that it isn't. But you do have a point, it has the side effect of physically re-ordering part of the DOM.

Comment: I would assume that since the OP said, "I can't assign an individual class to", that would imply the inability to add a unique ID.  But I'm not saying yours is a bad answer; I obviously haven't down-voted you.  I'm just saying that it isn't how I'd do it.

Comment: No need to be defensive, I completely understand your objection. Only the OP can decide. I like to rely on the DOM for this kind of state transfer if it makes the overall code simpler, but it is a matter of taste and the situation.

Answer (score 2):

@tgifred
In the end, I managed to find the working solution.
It is like this. I hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="aclass">
    <li class="animate">Panel 1</li>
    <li class="animate">Panel 2</li>
    <li class="animate">Panel 3</li>
    <li class="animate">Panel 4</li>
    <li class="animate">Panel 5</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var elements = $("ul#aclass  li");
        elements.hide();
        elements.each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(2000* i++).fadeIn(2000);
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In case you want to have visible only one element at a time, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var elements = $("ul#aclass  li");
        elements.hide();
        elements.each(function (i) {
            $(this).delay(2000 * i++).fadeIn(20).fadeOut(1800);
        });

    });
</script>
```

And you can play with the easing.

Comment: This code does not run and the answer stops in the middle of a sentence. I'm not sure how it gathered 2 upvotes.

Comment: Nope, would never work, it's a loop that toggles the class on all the elements at the same time, and it does so every two seconds, at least it would have if the syntax errors were fixed.

Comment: You are right, my code is not solving his problem. It was meant, at that time, to hint in a direction that can solve the problem. My code never claimed it would work. But it would be what I would try. And that was the use of CSS classes. I still think that there is something to that, and I will comeback with a solution when I have the time. For now, I will edit the response and have at the top some code that works and almost makes what it was asked to do, but not really. I need to think a bit more for the real solution, but the real solution is not presented around, from what I see.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function with a variable that increments for each run, something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function showpanel(i, elems) {
        i = i === elems.length-1 ? 0 : i+1;
        elems.eq(i).show(0).delay(1000).hide(0, function() {
            showpanel(i, elems);
        });
    })(-1, $("ul#aclass > li"));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ft9tb2cb/)

Comment: The calculation of `i` could be simplified a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/ft9tb2cb/1/ (I'm wondering why `1` instead of `0` for the animation speed?)

Comment: @Tomalak - `0` works as well, the point is that there has to be a number given for jQuery to add it to the FX queue and make `delay` work, and I usually use `1` as one millisecond isn't noticeable and it's clearer to me that the animated version of show/hide is being used etc. I initially did [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ft9tb2cb/2/) but tried to make it at least look a little less complicated by splitting it up a little.

Comment: Hm, my understanding is that if you pass `0` then the animated version of show/hide isn't used - at least my variant switches the panels without visual jitter (`1` is in fact notable on my machine).

Comment: Any value would trigger the animated version, without it `delay` wouldn't work. I don't see any more jitter with a millisecond, but zero works, it still uses the animated version, just with a zero delay, so it doesn't matter really, so if that gives less jitter, why not.

Comment: I have most definitely a slower machine. Good point about the animated version, I'm just not sure if I completely understand. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/ft9tb2cb/3/ (note `.show()` without a number, but `.hide(0)`). When changed to `.hide()`, it stops working. So apprarently "without delay it wouldn't work" is not the entirey truth, otherwise it would stop after the `.show()`.

Comment: The `show` doesn't need to be delayed, the `hide` does, so the `show` doesn't really have to be added to the FX queue at all, but `hide()` has to.

Comment: Obviously. But why? Don't make me dig through the jQuery source. :)

Comment: `show` comes before `delay`, it happens immediately anyway. `delay` only delays animations that comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $.next().

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function showpanel($toShow, $toHide) {  
        if ($toHide) {
            $toHide.hide();
        }
        $toShow.show();
        setTimeout(showpanel, 200, $toShow.next(), $toShow)
    });

    showpanel($("ul#aclass > li").hide().first())

});
```

Answer (score 0):

check it out:

```
function showpanel(current, elems) {
    return function() {
        current = current < elems.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
        elems.hide().eq(current).show();
    }
 };

setInterval(showpanel(0, $("#aclass li")), 200)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q96kqt6n/1/)